# flask_mail, mails are stuck on thread and never sent

Tags: python, ssl, socket.io, flask-mail

I'm using flask + socketio with ssl, and I'm trying to send mail, but for some reason, sending mail is not working.

Here is my configuration:

```
app.config['MAIL_SERVER']='smtp.gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 465
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'xxx@gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = 'xxx;'
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = False
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True
app.config['DEBUG'] = True

mail=Mail(app)
```

...

And when I'm using it:

```
@app.route('/testMail')
def testMail():
    msg = Message(
              'Hello',
           sender='xxx@gmail.com',
           recipients=['xxx@gmail.com'])
    msg.body = "This is the email body"
    mail.send(msg)

    return ""
```

And here is the error log:

> File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py",
>   line 307, in flush
>       self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])   File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 721, in sendall
>       v = self.send(data[count:])   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 687, in send
>       **v = self._sslobj.write(data) error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe**
>
> ...
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line
>   156, in configure_host
>       host = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(self.mail.server, self.mail.port)   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py",
>   line 796, in **init**
>       SMTP.**init**(self, host, port, local_hostname, timeout)   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py",
>   line 256, in **init**
>       (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py",
>   line 316, in connect
>       self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py",
>   line 801, in _get_socket
>       new_socket = socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)   File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py",
>   line 575, in create_connection
>   **raise err error: [Errno 65] No route to host**

For some reason, I can't send any email. It seems stuck because of the socketio + ssl wrapping. I've got no idea on how to configure the right way.

Comment: There is `No route to host` in the error log. Check the network connection to the server and port from your program. It may be prohibited by a firewall.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, if your are working in a virtual machine check the network connection for the `ssh` port, in my case i work with `vagrant`, I enabled connection  for the `ssh` port, this code works to me:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_mail import Mail, Message

# object Flask and object Mail

app = Flask(__name__)
#configuration flask to Mail
app.config.update(
             MAIL_SERVER = "smtp.gmail.com",
             MAIL_PORT = 465,
             MAIL_USERNAME = 'xxx@gmail.com',  #user mail
             MAIL_PASSWORD = 'xxx',
             MAIL_USE_TLS = False,
             MAIL_USE_SSL = True,
             MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER  =  'xxx@gmail.com', #user that will go email)
mail = Mail(app)

@app.route("/index")
def index():
    return "ok"


@app.route("/Test Mail")
def test_mail():
    """route to test email by flask mail."""
    msj = "This is a test to send mail with flask."
    recipients = ["xxxemail@gmail.com"]
    msg_object = Message("hello", recipients)
    msg_object.body = "Hello, this email is a test"
    mail.send(msg_object)
    return "Sent"



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=7000, debug=True)
```

Also, you should verify if the built-insecurity features in `Gmail service` may block this login attempt. Log in your account and Visit https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps.